# Apply background image to Bootstrap column, but giving 0 height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't seem to figure this one out.

I want to have a background image which should be applied in the right hand part of a div, and thought using Bootstrap columns would be the best responsive way to do this.  But, the image isn't showing, as the height of the column div is always 1 pixel, regardless of CSS.

Why is this and how can I set it to be the full height of the other div?

HTML

```
<div id="procedure-singleReview" class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2 class="bv-brand">Here's what a happy client says...</h2>
            <blockquote>
                <?php echo $sidebarReviews[0]->post_excerpt;?>
                <footer><?php echo get_post_meta($sidebarReviews[0]->ID,'client_name',true);?> <span class="rating rating-<?php echo get_post_meta($sidebarReviews[0]->ID, 'rating', true);?>"></span></footer>
            </blockquote>
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($sidebarReviews[0]->ID);?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read full review</a> <a href="/testimonial-reviews/" class="btn btn-default">Read all reviews</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm img"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#procedure-singleReview .img {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://placehold.it/800x600);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: would you try `background-size:100%;` ?

Comment: Although I have tried that, and it didn't change the height, that only affects the display of the background image within the container (in this case 1 pixel high). Anyway, I don't want to use the background-size as 100%, as I want it to specifically use `cover` to fill the space of the div.

Comment: `height: 100%` does not work. you need a set height on the parent element (like 100px) if you want to use it this way. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1max0ry9/

Comment: I don't want to use a fixed height

Comment: Yes that's mostly the problem. But `height:100%` simply doesn't work the way most people want it. You can use `position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;` if you want to stretch it over the whole element. But be aware that you than need another child element because absolute elements are taken out of the flow.

Comment: Or use flexbox, but flexbox is not supported by ie less than or equal IE9 as shown here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. What you can also do is, using the background image as real img. I also read that there's a trick how a background image behaves as real image but you have to google for that I guess..

Comment: I don't wish to use an img tag, as it's not vital to the content of the display, so for SEO purposes, a background image is the best suitability. So, is there no way this can be done? Surely that's not the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#procedure-singleReview{display:flex;}
```

```css
#procedure-singleReview .img {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
  
}
#procedure-singleReview{display:flex;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="procedure-singleReview" class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2 class="bv-brand">Here's what a happy client says...</h2>
            <blockquote>
                <?php echo $sidebarReviews[0]->post_excerpt;?>
                <footer><?php echo get_post_meta($sidebarReviews[0]->ID,'client_name',true);?> <span class="rating rating-<?php echo get_post_meta($sidebarReviews[0]->ID, 'rating', true);?>"></span></footer>
            </blockquote>
            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($sidebarReviews[0]->ID);?>" class="btn btn-primary">Read full review</a> <a href="/testimonial-reviews/" class="btn btn-default">Read all reviews</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 hidden-xs img">sfsfsfsdfsfsfs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am using col-sm class in your case leave as it is just add #procedure-singleReview{display:flex;} in you style sheet

Comment: Why does changing the parent div to `flex`, cause the `row` div to shorten it's width? it's not 100% any more

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `min-height` to your div. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lmj2tdu/2/)

```
#procedure-singleReview .img {
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_284x96dp.png);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100%;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to use fixed heights, as the content in the left hand pane will change the height of the container div

Comment: Then i think that you just should put you background as an image inside the div